# Bootstrap 5.0 Navbar Dropdown not working

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-5

I couldn't make the dropdown on my navbar work. When I click on it nothing happens. What might be the problem? I checked similar posts but couldn't find a solution. Am I missing a script or something?

layout.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar" style="background-color: #e6e2c2;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="{% static 'potbs/potbs.png' %}" alt="Logo" width="50" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
                Pat on the Back Studios.
            </a>
        
            <div class="navbar-expand" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Profile
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Earned Badges</a></li>
                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    {% else %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please use bootstrap.bundle.min.js. as the version above 5 have a dependency on popper.js, this bundle have that included.

Comment: @JyothishBhaskaran thank you I think I already have it at the bottom as the first script. Is that what you were talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript imports used in this code are the following:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

So Bootstrap is imported two times. `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` already imports Popper + Bootstrap so in order to make the dropdown work, you need to remove the two last lines and keep `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` import:

```html
<!-- Import to keep -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Lines to remove -->
<!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
```